# react js Input type select get name

Tags: reactjs, select, input

i have this input select based onstate data

```
            <Input
              type="select"              
              className=""
              placeholder=""
              onChange={this.handleLDMapprove}
              >
            {this.state.asp_data.map((asp) => (
              <option value={asp.Vendor_Code}>{asp.Name}</option>
            ))}
            </Input>
```

usually i have no problem for get `value={asp.Vendor_Code}`, but this time i need to get the `{asp.Name}'`. how i'd do that?

here's my code for onChange

```
  handleLDMapprove = (e) => {
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    let bodymrApprove = {
      "dsp_company_code": value,
    "dsp_company": name,
    }  
    console.log('bodymrApprove ', bodymrApprove);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you wanted to get selected text from select input. If yes then please have look on the following example. Hope it helps you.

```
handleLDMapprove = (e) => {
    let name = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text;
    let value = e.target.value;
    let bodymrApprove = {
      "dsp_company_code": value,
    "dsp_company": name,
    }  
    console.log('bodymrApprove ', bodymrApprove);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get label of selected option as `e.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].innerHTML`